# How to add some fancy old style decoration in four corners of margins?

Tags: margins, book-design, decorations, layout

I would like to add some fancy-looking, **old style decorations in the four corners** of each page of the main part of a document, while keeping a small gap from the paper's edge to allow printing.

Here's a MWE code to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage[pagestyles,medium]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{principal}{
    \sethead[\thepage][][\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}]    {\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}}{}{\thepage}
    \headrule
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{principal}

TEST

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview of what this code is currently doing.  I've shown in red the kind of decoration I would like to add (and the same, reversed, at the bottom of page).  I don't know what LaTeX may have as old style decoration patterns, so any suggestion is a plus :

[image]

Take note that the patterns must be symetric relative to the text, so there should be a larger gap on a side, where there's a margin of 1.5 inch.

As an option, the patterns may be a bit different on the left and the right pages, to add some variety.

Any suggestion about how to do this fancy old-style book trick?

Comment: Perhaps look at [`ornaments`](//texdoc.net/pkg/ornaments).

Comment: Also the *Glisterings* column in TUGboat 2011  http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf

Comment: The package ornaments stops the  compilation. I’m yet unable to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following for fancy invoices. I am sure it was inspired by some answer here at SE but did not put any link in comment. You have to compile twice.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{\eachpageornament}}

\newcommand{\eachpageornament}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,color=black,every node/.style={inner sep=5mm}]
        \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){\pgfornament[width=25mm]{37}};
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){\pgfornament[width=25mm,symmetry=v]{37}};
        \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){\pgfornament[width=25mm,symmetry=h]{37}};
        \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){\pgfornament[width=25mm,symmetry=c]{37}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting PDF]